# SQL Maintenance Plan Fails but the Cleanup task deletes all the back up files

Tags: sql-server

the database was detached by someone and the Maintenance plan job failed. it did not create new Backups and the old backups were deleted, i don't have a way to restore db now. How can i change the maintenance plan to delete the old backups only when New backup file is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it adding before `Back Up Database Task` and after with green line (success) `Maintenance Cleanup Taks`.

In this way the cleanup is performed only if the backup has been completed successfully.

Below an example of the workflow with 4 weeks of retention (the job is scheduled every day)
[image]

> You won't be able to check the variables via a simple maintenance plan
> you create in SQL Management Studio. You will need to either script it
> out and put it in a SQL job or create a full-on SSIS package. SSIS
> will provide you with all of the maintenance plan tasks that are
> available via SSMS as well as all of the other benefits of SSIS
> including package variables that you can use in your precedence
> constraints

Reference [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/47117/add-conditions-to-maintenance-plan-sequence-on-sql-server)

Comment: If i have the new back file and the old backup file in the folder and the cleanup task execute , i want to have a conditional delete of the old file where the old backup file is deleted only if the new back up file is present. How can i change the cleanup task this way

Comment: In my example, the cleanup task will only run if the backup was successful

Comment: Thank you for the help. Was able to fix it.